# How do I say "what technologies should be *used* in a project"?

Tags: synonyms

Hey, I'd need a synonym for *used* in this phrase, because the meaning is from the "long term" point of view, something like:

> What technologies should be **employed** in a project for it to succeed in following 10 years?

If I use *used* it seems like we take advantage of this technology right know; that's not the meaning I need.

I'm using this kind of sentence very often in a documentation and I need a substitution for *often*.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What technologies should be **adopted**...

**Examples**

- [Originally conceived by IBM in 1997, the EJB 1.0 and 1.1 specifications were **adopted** by Sun in 1999.](http://books.google.com/books?id=OkKJ2JGMcCAC&pg=PA50&dq=adopt+Hibernate&hl=en&ei=7HnvTO-HDZK0hAeww8X2Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA) *Spring Persistence with Hibernate* (2010)
- [To get the benefits of ORM for non-J2EE applications, programmers typically **adopt** an alternative ORM framework, the most popular of which is Hibernate.](http://books.google.com/books?id=YpeP0ok0cO4C&pg=PT356&dq=adopt+Hibernate&hl=en&ei=7HnvTO-HDZK0hAeww8X2Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ) *MySQL stored procedure programming* (2006)
- [Unfortunately, users with Rails experience who **adopt** Grails are in for a few surprises because the tools are really quite different](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ddwyg3ADVCEC&pg=PA266&dq=adopt+Hibernate&hl=en&ei=7HnvTO-HDZK0hAeww8X2Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBg) *The definitive guide to Grails* (2009)

**Note:** nothing wrong with *use* and *employ* though.

Comment: this is definitely what I was going for :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Implemented* would give the sense of being used when the technologies need to be used, not before.

Comment: hey, I mean technologies that are already implemented, I guess there's now proper substitution in this sense. I'm not sure whether the "employed" could be used here

Comment: *Employed* works. You could also try *utilized*.

Comment: @Robusto: -1 for 'utilized' - it is a word that is over-utilized and would be better used less often.

Comment: 'Utilized' is a slightly longer way of saying 'used'.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: -1 for trying to help? After the OP announced he was looking for synonyms for "used"? Well, I guess it's true that no good deed goes unpunished.

Comment: @Robusto: actually - I gave '-1' nominally to your comment (which, of course, is an impossible operation); I had not noticed that you also gave the answer.  Sorry to mislead.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer: So your point is that you were downvoting a question you did not notice was mine because of a comment I made, and you were unaware and unconcerned that you could have been downvoting someone else's answer? Do you always downvote questions because you disagree with one or another comment made in response to it? There is a reason making a down vote on comments is, as you say, "an impossible operation."

Comment: @Robusto: no; I did not actually downvote anything.  I said '-1' for your comment, not noticing that instead of editing your answer to add the extra alternatives, you had added a comment to your own answer.  Careless - yes; it was late at night.  Sorry!  (And had you edited the answer, I would not have down-voted you.  I was trying, but failing, to be playful.)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer: OK, clarification noted and apology graciously accepted. In the future, however, please be aware that putting "-1" or "+1" in a comment is a convention used in these forums to indicate votes a person has actually taken.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to make the phrase more active:

- What technologies should the project use for it to succeed over the next 10 years?

I also think that *use* is a perfectly sensible word to use in the context; short, sweet, simple.  If you need an alternative, then *employ* is probably one of the better options.

Comment: +1 - Simplest/preferred = 'Used'. Reasonable alternative = 'employed'.

Answer (score 0):

> What technologies should be *leveraged*…

Comment: No, no, no! The definition of this word makes its use in the context rather dubious; but regardless, it's a 'buzzword bingo' kind of term, and should be avoided when there are clearer alternatives.